# Returning a getters in a computed create a loop

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I am calling inside the computed an action from the store to run it and after I am returning a getter, this will create a loop.

The HTML

```
{{loadedProjects}}
```

The computed

```
computed: {
    loadedProjects() {
      this.$store.dispatch("getProjects");
      return this.$store.getters.loadedProjects;
    }
  }
```

The store

```
import Vuex from "vuex";
import axios from "axios";

const createStore = () => {
    return new Vuex.Store({
        state: {

            loadedProjects: []
        },
        mutations: {
            setProjects(state, projects) {
                state.loadedProjects = projects
            }

        },
        actions: {
            getProjects(vuexContext) {
                console.log("hello1")
                return axios.get("THE API URL")
                    .then(res => {
                        console.log("hello2")
                        vuexContext.commit("setProjects", res.data);
                    })
                    .catch(e => console.log(e));
            }

        },
        getters: {
              loadedProjects(state) {
                return state.loadedProjects;
              }
        }
    });
};

export default createStore;
```

I expect to call my action to populate my state and after to return my state to render my data.

Comment: Computed variables shouldn't have side effects.

Comment: @StevenB. what do you mean ? any reference for that ?

Comment: @StevenB. what do you mean? so how should I do to have what i expect?

Comment: @LucaSpezzano you can dispatch "getProjects" in the `created` hook

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the point of using the store action that makes an API call inside the computed property ... maybe you want to trigger `loadedProjects` change ? ....computed property is not asynchronous so either way the return line will be executed before the you get the response... you might try [vue-async-computed](https://github.com/foxbenjaminfox/vue-async-computed) plugin OR just use the call on the `created` hook like you have done which is the better way and you don't have to use a computed property you can just `{{ $store.getters.loadedProjects }}` on  your template

Answer (score 1):

Computed properties should not have side effects (e.g. calling a store action, changing data, and so on). Otherwise it can happen that the triggered side effect could lead to a re-rendering of the component and possible re-fetching of the computed property. Thus, an infinite loop

Comment: Thanks a lot :) So is better as i did in the previous answer?

Comment: Yes, definitely!

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code like that:

```
created: function () {
  this.$store.dispatch("getProjects")
},
computed: {
  loadedProjects() {
    return this.$store.getters.loadedProjects
  }
}
```

It is working now but I would like to know but I have that problem working inside the computed and also I wonder if it's the best solution. Any help????